# Display Audio & Video Files In TreeView on Clicking Any Drive (QFileSystemModel)

Tags: qt, qt4, filesystems, qfilesystemmodel

I want to traverse the drives present in my system and search for audio/video files inside it. Basically traverse the sub directories and display the file inside the treeview. I have 2 tree views, One to display System Directories and other to display audio/video files.

```
// Displays System Drives inside TreeView(Drive View) When Application Starts
void PanasonicViewer::onCamStartup()
{
    m_SystemModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
    m_SystemListViewModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
    m_SystemModel->setRootPath(QDir::currentPath());
    ui->DriveView->setModel(m_SystemModel); //Left side TreeView
    ui->DriveListView->setModel(m_SystemListViewModel); //Right Side TreeView

    // regard less how many columns you can do this using for:
    for(int nCount = 1; nCount < m_SystemModel->columnCount(); nCount++)
       ui->DriveView->hideColumn(nCount);
}

//On Clicking The TreeView, it should display Audio and Video files in DriveListView
void PanasonicViewer::on_DriveView_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    QStringList sDriveFilters;

    QString sPath = m_SystemModel->fileInfo(index).absoluteFilePath();
    ui->DriveListView->setRootIndex(m_SystemListViewModel->setRootPath(sPath));    

    m_SystemModel->setRootPath(QDir::currentPath());
    m_SystemModel->setFilter(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::AllDirs );
    m_SystemListViewModel->setFilter( QDir::Files | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot );

    sDriveFilters << "*.aac" << "*.wmv" << "*.avi" << "*.mpeg" << "*.mov" << "*.3gp" << "*.flv" << "*.mp3" ;

    m_SystemListViewModel->setNameFilters(sDriveFilters);
    m_SystemListViewModel->setNameFilterDisables(false);
}
```

You can notice in the above click event that I have set Filter to selected extensions. This seems to work and displays audio and video files when I click a drive i.e. E:\ but doesnt display the files present inside subfolders. Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to what you're setting for [`QFileSystemModel::filter`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qfilesystemmodel.html#filter).

The default setting for is `QDir::AllEntries | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::AllDirs`, where `QDir::AllEntries` translates to `QDir::Dirs | QDir::Files | QDir::Drives`. If we expand it out, the default setting is:

```
QDir::Dirs | QDir::Files | QDir::Drives | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::AllDirs
```

By calling `m_SystemModel->setFilter(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::AllDirs )`, you're telling the model that you only want to see standard directories, and want to exclude all files. Just remove your call to `setFilter` altogether and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply buddy. I removed `SetFilter` as mentioned above, but it doesnt work. Still doesnt display audio/video files :(

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
ui->DriveListView->setRootIndex(m_SystemListViewModel->setRootPath(sPath));
```

to

```
m_SystemListViewModel->setRootPath(sPath)
ui->DriveListView->setRootIndex(m_SystemListViewModel->index(sPath);
```

I'm skeptical whether the QModelIndex returned by `setRootPath` is the one you think it is. Troubleshoot this by removing the filter from m_SystemListViewModel to make sure that you're actually viewing the folder that you think you are.

I know that this should work if sPath is a directory path. I'm not sure if it'll work as expected if it's a file path.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It doesn't work even if I change as you mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

What you expect is not what the standard `QFileSystemModel` is supposed to do. What you need is to manually extract the multimedia files recursively in `QStringListModel` and set it on your `QListView`, or directly use `QListWidget` to add items directly while enumerating. When the selection over the `QFileSystemModel` changes you can get the path of the selected folder and enumerate the files and the subfolder files recursively. Note that if you click accedentally some drive you will end-up waiting for all the multimedia files in your drive. If that is what you want then maybe you may consider enumerating in worker thread which is not so easy.